# How can I sort the nested list by parent and child list in vb.net?

Tags: vb.net

I have a list with nested list. Below is sample code. I need to sort by topic -> name by ascending order and each topic Indicator also sort with ascending order. For this is there any linq method in VB.NET.

```
Public Class Topic
    Public Property id As String
    Public Property name As String
    Public Property Indicators As List(Of Indicator) = New List(Of Indicator)()
End Class
Public Class Indicator
    Public Property id As String
    Public Property name As String
End Class
Dim topics As List(Of Topic) = New List(Of Topic)
Dim t As Topic = New Topic
Dim i As Indicator= New Indicator
t.id = 1
t.name = "Energy Broken Down By Renewable"
i.id = 1
i.name = "Mike"
t.Indicators.Add(i)
i.id = 2
i.name = "Bob"
t.Indicators.Add(i)
topics.Add(t)
t.id = 2
t.name = "Estimated Energy Consumption By Source"
i.id = 1
i.name = "Cleark"
t.Indicators.Add(i)
i.id = 2
i.name = "Who"
t.Indicators.Add(i)
i.id = 3
i.name = "Hood"
t.Indicators.Add(i)
topics.Add(t)
```

Thank You
Bobbin.

Comment: If you want to sort a `List` in-place then you wouldn't use LINQ in the first place. The Q in LINQ stands for Query, i.e. LINQ is about reading data. A LINQ query will enable you to read data from a `List` in various ways, including ordered, and you could then create a new `List` from the data you read. That's not going to affect the original `List` though. If you want to sort a `List` in-place then call its `Sort` method. If each item in that `List` has a child `List` that you want to sort, call `Sort` on each child `List` too. LINQ is not magic.

Comment: Just an FYI, your example code will result in the `topics` list holding a single `Topic` object twice. The `Topic` object will have a list holding the same Indicator object 5 times.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to permanently sort topics and indicators, don't use LINQ, use `Sort()`:

```
topics.Sort(Function(t1, t2) t1.name.CompareTo(t2.name))
For Each t In topics
    t.Indicators.Sort(Function(i1, i2) i1.name.CompareTo(i2.name))
Next
```

If you want to leave the topics and indicators unsorted, but you want to see a sorted view of these objects, you can use this LINQ query:

```
Dim sorted_view = From t In topics
                  Order By t.name
                  Select New Topic With {.id = t.id,
                                         .name = t.name,
                                         .Indicators = (From i In t.Indicators
                                                        Order By i.name).ToList()}
```

But keep in mind that the results of this LINQ query won't have the original `Topic` objects. Instead you'll be viewing new copies of the original `Topic`s, each with a new sorted list of `Indicators`.